# Unable to build toolchain because PATH contains spaces, TABs, and/or newline (\n) characters

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, windows-subsystem-for-linux, buildroot, toolchain

I'm working on a Buildroot project on Raspberry 4. I wanted to start by building a cross-compilation toolchain :

```
make toolchain
```

but I'm stuck on this error output:

```
Your PATH contains spaces, TABs, and/or newline (\n) characters.                                                                                          
This doesn't work. Fix you PATH.                                                                                                                               
make: *** [support/dependencies/dependencies.mk:27: dependencies] Error 1
```

Could the problem be linked to the $PATH variable? If so, how can I fix it?

I specify that I am using windows-subsystem-for-Linux, and I choose Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: Run this command : `printf "%q\n" "$PATH"` If you see any of `\n\r\t`, they could be the culprits.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a build script and override the PATH variable:

```
setlocal
set PATH=/bin;/usr/local/bin;/usr/bin
make toolchain
endlocal
```

I included [setlocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setlocal) to make the environment changes only apply for the batch file execution. You'll probably need to add additional paths if those I've included aren't sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I also found this issue while building buildroot for windows-subsystem-for-Linux. I resolved it by following below steps:

1. echo $PATH
2. Copy path on notepad++ or some other test editor
3. remove all paths with spaces.
4. use export command to rewrite the PATH

> export PATH=/path/1:/path/2

5. Finally I run the make command again. It worked

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'sudo make' and it will solve your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).